# Ruby + HTTParty—how to send a POST request with data-binary?

Tags: ruby, post, httparty

I have the following `curl` that works:

```
curl 'https://externalsite.com/ForgotPasswordSubmit.action' \
-X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----qwertyuiop' \
--data-binary $'------qwertyuiop\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="xsrf_token"\r\n\r\nnull\r\n------qwertyuiop\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="emailAddr"\r\n\r\nmy_email_address@gmail.com\r\n------qwertyuiop--\r\n'
```

I'm trying to get a Ruby + Sinatra app to do the same thing, but it's not working. Here's my latest attempt:

```
HTTParty.post "https://externalsite.com/ForgotPasswordSubmit.action", :headers => {"Content-Type"=>"multipart/form-data; boundary=----qwertyuiop"}, :body => '------qwertyuiop\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="xsrf_token"\r\n\r\nnull\r\n------qwertyuiop\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="emailAddr"\r\n\r\nmy_email@gmail.com\r\n------qwertyuiop--\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it to work with `curb`. The main problem was that `curl`'s `$'my_string\n'` type of string turns `\r\n` characters into new lines, whereas in ruby I was trying `'my_string\n'` which was automatically parsed to `my_string\\n`. By changing to use double quotes I fixed that problem.

Final working code is:

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new('https://externalsite.com/ForgotPasswordSubmit.action')
curl.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----qwertyuiop"
data = "------qwertyuiop\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"xsrf_token\"\r\n\r\nnull\r\n------qwertyuiop\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"emailAddr\"\r\n\r\n#{email}\r\n------qwertyuiop--\r\n"
curl.post_body=data
curl.http_post
```